# Is the orbit of Earth really closed?

Tags: general-relativity, classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, solar-system

So I know that Earth's orbit around the sun is elliptical (about there common center of mass) if we ignore the other perturbations in Newtonian gravity.

Is the orbit of a planet around a star closed in Einstein gravity, if we ignore the other perturbations?

Comment: I'm not going to dupehammer this, but I think it is effectively a duplicate of [Runge-Lenz vector and Keplerian Orbits](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60393/). This discusses how there are no closed orbits in GR because the RL vector is not conserved. Note also that in GR all orbits decay by emission of gravitational waves.

Comment: In practice (and this applies to Newtonian gravity as well as GR), there are _no_ closed orbits when the number of bodies in the universe is greater than two.  It is possible to find _degenerate_ three-body closed orbits, but these are entirely contrived examples (e.g. two dimensional figure-of-eight), and are unstable n any case.

Comment: @m4r35n357 to be fair the question does say "if we ignore the other perturbations" i.e. it is asking only about GR.

Comment: @JohnRennie I think the question was edited after my comment.  Of course now I agree!

Answer (score 1):

One of the results from Einstein's General Relativity was about the precession of the orbits of planets.
There was an unexplained precession of 43" per century for Mercury that GR accounted for.

The same happens for the Earth, but the effect is smaller.

So the orbit is far from closed.  There will be larger effects too from the influence of other planets.